# Customised Horizontal progress bar in Android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-xml, android-progressbar

I want a customised progress bar in android, like this:
[image]

I want progress bar same as it is, but unable to achieve this.

Comment: Try from this implementation https://github.com/saisasanksunkavalli/RoundedHorizontalProgressBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the result that you want:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:progress="80"
        app:indicatorColor="@color/blue_500"
        app:trackColor="@color/blue_200"
        app:trackThickness="16dp"
        app:trackCornerRadius="100dp"
        />
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**app:indicatorColor**: This is the color of the indicator, it depends on the value of `android:progress`

**app:trackColor**: This is the color of the track, it is the background color of the `LinearProgressIndicator`

**app:trackThickness**: This is the thickness of the track, which means that this value is the height of the `LinearProgressIndicator`

**Note:** The `MaterialCardView` should be inside a `ViewGroup` ( `ConstraintLayout`, `LinearLayout` ... ).